# debug some PHP code

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to make login with angularjs and PHP. But hitting problem I cannot understand why?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
session_start();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($data->password);

{

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","thanh03021986","erp");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }   

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email, password FROM user WHERE email = '$email'"); 
    $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($query); 

    if($numrow > 0){    

        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
                $dbemail = $rows['email'];
                $dbpassword = $rows['password'];            
        }
        $con->close();
        if($email==$dbemail && $password == $dbpassword){
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $email;
            header('location:/A.php');
        }       
    }
}
?>
```

When the `If()` return `true` the  `$_SESSION['uid'] = $email` works but the `header('location:/A.php');` does not work. I try to put `header('location:/A.php');` out of `IF()`, header works ??? Please help and explain?

Answer (score 1):

The `session_start` function must be called first as well as the `header` function must me called before any HTML code.

See the `header`function [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: When I try to take header out of IF() block, it works, when put inside IF() it does not work even though $_SESSION work????

Answer (score 1):

The redirection with `header`, you must be sure that there's nothing in the html already (not even the `<html>` tag), and an absolute path. So, you should do this in order to work:

```
header('Location: http://pathblablabla.bla/A.php');
```

Also, note that I put Location, not location. Not sure if it's case-sensitive, but just in case...

Comment: 'if($email == $dbemail && $password == $dbpassword ){ 
   $_SESSION['uid'] = $email;
   header("Location:/index.html"); exit;
  }'

Comment: @user2671755 Change this: ´header("Location:/index.html")´ to this: ´header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/index.html")´, where yourdomain.com it's... exactly that. If you where google, it would be google.com